# Change the Default setting on Allow items from this list to appear in search results?

Tags: list

How Can I change the Default setting on Allow items from this list to appear in search results? to "No"   I'd like maybe a feature to set the default setting to "No"

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Event Receiver for the site that triggers once a list is created and have it set the setting for you.  If you haven't done event receivers before, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx